# Preciso criar um relatório que faça o somatório de valores por categoria e agrupe essa informações de acordo com a origem

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso criar um relatório que faça o somatório de valores por categoria e agrupe essa informações de acordo com a origem. Explico: Preciso trazer o somatório de valores de mensalidade, matrícula, material e taxas, mas agrupando essas  informações por categoria de Turma. As turmas se diferenciam pelas letras iniciais (TB%, TC%, TE%...).
Consegui fazer o somatório dos valores, mas não consegui agrupar por categoria de turmas (trazer estes valores para todas as turmas que comecem com TB% numa linha, com TC% em outra, etc).

```
SELECT
    UNIDADE, TURMA,
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('000','001','002') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as "MENSALIDADE",
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('003','004') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as "MATRÍCULA",
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('005','006', '007') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as "MATERIAL",
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX NOT IN ('000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007') THEN VALORPAG ELSE 0 END) as "TAXAS",
    ROUND(SUM(VALORPAGO),0) as "TOTAL"
FROM
    DEBITOS
WHERE
    UNIDADE = '008'
    AND DATAPAGO BETWEEN '2021-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-05-31 00:00:00.000'
    AND VALORPAGO IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
    UNIDADE, TURMA
```

[image: Resultado do select]

Comment: Como se precisa da saída dos dados ? A categoria , em tese , pode ser montada por meio da FUNCTION SUBSTRING mas ao menos para mim ficou pouco a forma requerida da saída.

Comment: Ah! Sim.
Preciso dos valores totais de cada coluna:  Na coluna TURMA todas as turmas TB% agrupadas em uma única linha categoria Turma B  e preciso somar todos os valores de Mensalidade dessas turmas e exibir o total, da mesma forma para Matrícula, Material, etc).
Todas as turmas TC% agrupadas em uma única linha categoria Turma C.
Não sei se consegui esclarecer...

Comment: Você precisa das somas por turma e categoria de turma ou só por categoria de turma? Se for só por categoria experimente trocar onde está `Turma` para `Left(Turma, 2)`

Comment: Preciso por categoria de turma (juntar os valores de todas que começam com TB%, depois todos os valores das que começam com TC%. Isso pra Mensalidade, Matricula etc). ;)

Comment: Experimente fazer uns testes da forma que sugeri anteriormente, trocando `Turma` por `Left(Turma, 2)` no Select e no Group By

Comment: Deu certo, Imex. Só não consegui deixar com o nome que eu preciso ainda. Mas o problema do somatório foi resolvido.
Muitooo obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

tente com CUBE ou ROLLUP , gera um "running total" , não tive como testar todavia.

```
SELECT
    UNIDADE, 
    TURMA,
    SUBSTRING(TURMA,1,2) GRUPO,
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('000','001','002') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as "MENSALIDADE",
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('003','004') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as "MATRÍCULA",
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('005','006', '007') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as "MATERIAL",
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX NOT IN ('000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007') THEN VALORPAG ELSE 0 END) as "TAXAS",
    ROUND(SUM(VALORPAGO),0) as "TOTAL"
FROM
    DEBITOS
WHERE
    UNIDADE = '008'
    AND DATAPAGO BETWEEN '2021-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-05-31 00:00:00.000'
    AND VALORPAGO IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY CUBE (UNIDADE, 
               TURMA,
               SUBSTRING(TURMA,1,2))
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Tentei fazer o teste aqui, mas meu banco não permitiu. Vou precisar alterar o nível de compatibilidade do banco de dados e estou aguardando autorização pra isso. Assim que testar eu informo aqui.
Muito obrigada.

Comment: Estranho , acreditava ser padrão, mas ok.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar o comando WITH

Assim:

```
WITH RELATORIO AS (SELECT
    UNIDADE, TURMA,
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('000','001','002') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as 'MENSALIDADE',
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('003','004') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as 'MATRICULA',
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX IN ('005','006', '007') THEN VALORPAGO ELSE 0 END) as 'MATERIAL',
    SUM( CASE   WHEN CODTX NOT IN ('000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007') THEN VALORPAG ELSE 0 END) as 'TAXAS',
    ROUND(SUM(VALORPAGO),0) as 'TOTAL'
FROM
    DEBITOS
WHERE
    UNIDADE = '008'
    AND DATAPAGO BETWEEN '2021-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-05-31 00:00:00.000'
    AND VALORPAGO IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
    UNIDADE, TURMA )

SELECT TURMA,
SUM(MENSALIDADE), SUM(MATRICULA), SUM(MATERIAL), SUM(TAXAS), SUM(TOTAL)
FROM RELATORIO
GROUP BY TURMA
```